# Google Scripts - using variable with .getRange() function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically, I want to the user to be able to input their selected cell without hard coding.

Instead of what I have now: newFileBody.getRange('g4').setValue(email);

I have a config sheet where the user puts in values, and I'm pulling their response into this file. The user will type in what cell they want the information to be put in (let's say they also type 'g4', and that will be stored as "user_Variable").

I'd like it to be: newFileBody.getRange(user_Variable).setValue(email); where "user_Variable" is a specific cell they've typed in on the config sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The `getRange()` method can accept a string variable as long as it's a valid R1C1 notation, such as `G4`.

**Sample:**

```
function myFunction(userVariable) {
 // some code..

 newFileBody.getRange(userVariable).setValue(email);
 
// some more code..
}
```

**Documentation:**

[getRange() A1 Notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)